# Make a Formula to separate text and put in rows

Tags: excel

I need a strong Excel formula to do this:

- This is what I have now in my Excel File:

> |       EMAIL            |   COURSES    | 
>   |      a@a.com      |   course1, course2, course3    |

- And This is what I need looks like the Excel:

> |       EMAIL            |   COURSES    | 
>   |      a@a.com      |   course1    | 
>  
>   |      a@a.com      |   course2    | 
>   |      a@a.com      |   course3    |

Looks simple now but when you have 70K of cases you need a formula...

Comment: Use text to columns on the second column then use any of the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Scott thanks for your answer but believe me. I tried several ways before write in this site and one of those was the option "Text to Column" that have Excel in the DATA tab but for some unknow reason the system is not recognizing the comas after the text and is not separating properly the text... also that option only allow me to separate that text in columns not in rows...

Comment: Once you get them into columns then you would use the link I provided to unpivot the data. If excel will not recognize the commas with text to columns then what ever we suggest will not work either.  You need to find out why it does not recognize them as commas.  copy and paste one that does not work and use CODE() to see what the code is, then do the same with a comma types from the keyboard.